# Auto Fill Cell Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a sheet with two columns. A Date and Assist.

The sheet is filled out with a Date and with a number of how many assist.

What I would like is for the Assist column to automatically insert a 0 if there is a date entered and only if there is no number already in the Assist column.

I have the following script so far and it is triggered onOpen.

```
function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
  // sheet is the first worksheet in the spreadsheet
  var cell = sheet.getRange("J3:J"); 
  cell.setValue(0);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little slow, but works. Adapt as needed. It currently assumes your data are in columns A & B.

```
function storeValue() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A:B")

  for (var row = 1; dataRange.getNumRows(); row++) {
    if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue() != ''){
      if(sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue() == ''){
        sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(0); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```